# SQL Server table not updating in ArcGIS Online map

Tags: arcgis-server, sql-server, arcgis-online

I have a SQL Server table in my ArcGIS Online web app.
It is related to 2 other feature classes also in my map.

The source table is a non spatial table being related on a common field.
Not sure what more to add about the connection.
I've connected to the SQL Server table in ArcMap and related it to my feature classes then published it to ArcGIS Online

The SQL Server table is updated frequently, however these updates to the table are not reflected in my web app.
The updates are new values in existing columns.

I can see them in the .mxd locally, but they do not appear in the SQL Server table being used in my web app. I have not registered the connection on the ArcGIS Server host so the data is copied each time I publish the map service.

What can I do so that my SQL Server table updates with any new values entered into it from Microsoft Access?

Comment: Is the source table of a versioned feature class?  If so, what version is the connection made with, and what version is being edited?  Please **edit the question** to include details of the update and reconcile/post/compress procedures.

Comment: the source table is a non spatial table being related on a common field.  Not sure what more to add about the connection.  I've connected to the SQL Server table in ArcMap and related it to my feature classes then published it to ArcGIS Online.

Comment: Have you registered the connection in the ArcGIS Server host, or do you get a warning that the data will be copied when you publish the service? (please **edit the question** to answer comments requesting clarification -- It's not fair to those who would answer to have to review all the comments).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way ArcGIS Server can dynamically access a data table is if the service is published with a data source which is registered with the ArcGIS Server cluster.  If you don't have a registered data source, AGS will raise a warning in the publishing process, but will let you override that warning to make a static copy in a file geodatabase (which is copied to all nodes from which the service is published).  This condition is not an error, because there are times when you really do want to not be bothered with registration (for example, when publishing based on a pre-built cache), but it is not always a desirable outcome.

Since you *do* want dynamic table contents, you will need to follow the procedure for registering a data source with ArcGIS Server. Since there are several ways to accomplish this, I suggest you start with the [overview documentation](https://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/overview-register-data-with-arcgis-server.htm) then follow up with one of the "how to" pages appropriate to your environment.

Comment: Will this work with Microsoft SQL Server databases?  I don't see it as an option.

Comment: *ALL* supported databases, both SQL and no-SQL, are in the picklist -- [SQL-Server](https://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/register-sql-server-with-arcgis-server.htm) is between PostgreSQL and Teradata (though Microsoft drivers are not available on Linux platforms)